# perl DBI placeholder update stmt issue

Tags: sql, perl, sql-injection

A dbi placeholder has been used in the below sql 'update' queries to avoid sql injections recommended by perl doc. while testing , I noticed the new queries not working properly. I have been looking at stack-overflow and other recourses to identify if anything is missing or not.

```
#1
$sth = $dbh->do("UPDATE $dbstore SET Classes='" . $c_classes . "', zzzz='" . $c_zzzz . "', Timestamp='" . $timestamp . "' WHERE Host='" . $h_host . "'"); #old - working as expected
#$sth = $dbh->do("UPDATE $dbstore SET Classes=? , zzzz=? , Timestamp=? WHERE Host=? ", undef, $c_classes, $c_zzzz, $timestamp, $h_host); #new

#2
$sth = $dbh->do("UPDATE $dbstore SET Classes='" . $c_classes . "', zzzz='" . $c_zzzz . "', Timestamp='" . $timestamp . "' WHERE Host='" . $h_host . "'"); #old - working as expected
#$sth = $dbh->do("UPDATE $dbstore SET Classes=? , zzzz=? , Timestamp=? WHERE Host=?", undef, $c_classes, $c_zzzz, $timestamp, $h_host); #new

#3
$sth = $dbh->do("UPDATE $dbstore SET Warning='" . $st_warning . "' WHERE IDSID='" . $remote_user . "' AND Host='" . $st_host . "'"); #old - working as expected
#$sth = $dbh->do("UPDATE $dbstore SET Warning=? WHERE IDSID=? AND Host=?", undef, $st_warning, $remote_user, $st_host); #new

#4
$sth = $dbh->do("UPDATE $dbstore SET Warning='" . $st_warning . "' WHERE IDSID='" . $remote_user . "' AND Host='" . $st_host . "'"); #old - working as expected
#$sth =  $dbh->do("UPDATE $dbstore SET Warning=? WHERE IDSID=? AND Host=?", undef, $st_warning, $remote_user, $st_host); #new

#5
$sth = $dbh->do("UPDATE $dbxxxx SET Nodes='Submitted (" . $timestamp . " by " . $remote_user . ")', Configuration='" . $st_configuration . "' WHERE Host='" . $st_host . "'"); #old - working as expected
#$sth =  $dbh->do("UPDATE $dbxxxx SET Nodes='Submitted (? by ?)', Configuration=? WHERE Host=?", undef, $timestamp, $remote_user, $st_configuration, $st_host); #new

#6
$sth = $dbh->do("UPDATE $dbxxxx SET Classes='" . $n_classes_update . "' WHERE Host='" . $st_host . "'");  #old - working as expected
#$sth =  $dbh->do("UPDATE $dbxxxx SET Classes=? WHERE Host=?", undef, $n_classes_update, $st_host); #new
```

based on my understanding and reading (might be wrong), there is no need to surround the variables with a single/double quote.  Is this a true statement?

I am most suspicious to query number 5 'Submitted (? by ?)' part.  would having the ? inside single quote cause a problem in this case? if yes, what is the recommended solution?

Do you by chance see any issue on other queries?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got it, #5 is the problem.

`$dbh->do("UPDATE $dbxxxx SET Nodes='Submitted (? by ?)'", $timestamp, $remote_user)`

The above sets the string `Submitted (? by ?)`.

A placeholder is for a single SQL value. You build the string and pass it in.

You'll also want to use `quote_identifier` on the table name. This will quote and escape any identifiers, columns and table names, to avoid SQL injection that means.

```
my $q_table = $dbh->quote_identifier($dbxxxx);

$dbh->do("UPDATE $q_table SET Nodes=?", {}, "Submitted ($timestamp by $remote_user)");
```

Note that you should have gotten a warning or error about passing in too many arguments to the statement (I could be wrong, it's been a long time since I've used DBI), so you'll want to investigate why that did not happen. If at all possible, turn [`RaiseError`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#RaiseError) on so you get these SQL failures as errors immediately.

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect(
  $data_source, $username, $password, { RaiseError = 1 }
);
```

---

SQL design note. Avoid storing formatted data. It makes searching slow and complicated, increases table size, and limits your output formatting.

Format it on the way out. For example...

```
update some_table set submitted_at=?, remote_user=?

select concat('Submitted (', submitted_at, ' by ', remote_user, ')')
from some_table;
```

Comment: Bind values are the third+ arguments to [`do()`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#do) -- you want to stick an `undef` or `{}` in there.

Comment: number 5 was the issue and based on perl doc I have seen passing multiple placeholders https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#Placeholders_and_Bind_Values